# Event handling for social media share (linkedin and g plus)

Tags: jquery, linkedin-api

I am using linkedIn in my application. When i am sharing the url of my application, I also want to handle an event (function) which keeps log of the clicks and saves in database. I am having problem in dynamically handling the event while i share my url.

here is the html

```
<div class="linkedinShare ci-aling" linkedin data-url='{{url}}' data-title='{{title}}' data-summary="{{text}}" data-shares='linkedinshares'>{{linkedinshares}}</div>
```

here is the script function for linkedin which does not work

```
$.getScript('http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js', function () {
    debugger
    function handleLinkedInEvent(event) {
        debugger
        if (event) {
            EventService.UpdateEventAudit($scope.event_id, "LinkedIn", GetUrlReferrer());
        }
    }
    IN.Event.on(IN, 'systemReady', handleLinkedInEvent);
});
```

UpdateEventAudit is the function which i have to call while sharing the url to social media and save the log in database.

does anybody know where the problem is and why isn't it calling UpdateEventAudit  function?

Comment: You never call the `handleLinkedInEvent()` function you define. Presumably the share library you're using raises an event similar to `tweet` which you need to hook to for G+ and LinkedIn.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan how do i do that?

Comment: Start by reading their documentation

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan linkedin documentation?

Comment: No the documentation for the library you're using

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js this library?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan there's this way to handle events and call back function but it still doesn't call my function. any idea?
IN.Event.on(IN, LinkedIn, handleLinkedInEvent, callbackScope, extraData);

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding this correctly, you want to be able to track events when a user shares via linkedin...

I did try your code and after some R&D, found an alternative way to call the api...

created a mini-pen which you can view here https://codepen.io/craigiswayne/pen/Bqqbjz

Documentation on this subject can be found here: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin

```js
IN.Event.on(IN, 'systemReady', function() {
    var shareLink = document.getElementById('shareLink');
    shareLink.onclick = function(){
      event.preventDefault();
      var params = {
        "comment": "Check out developer.linkedin.com! " + this.getAttribute('href'),
        "visibility": {
          "code": "anyone"
        }
      };

      IN.API.Raw("/people/~/shares?format=json")
      .method("POST")
      .body(JSON.stringify(params))
      .result(StackOverflowDemo.updateShareCount)
      .error(function(errorMessage){
        StackOverflowDemo.logOutput('error occurred');
        console.log(errorMessage);
      });
    };

    document.body.appendChild(shareLink);

  });

  var StackOverflowDemo = {
    updateShareCount: function(result){
      var existingCount = parseInt( document.getElementById('count').value );
      existingCount = isNaN(existingCount) ? 0 : existingCount;
      document.getElementById('count').value =  existingCount + 1;
      StackOverflowDemo.logOutput( 'updated count' );
      StackOverflowDemo.logOutput( 'Total Shares = ' +  document.getElementById('count').value );
      StackOverflowDemo.logOutput( 'View Share here ' + result.updateUrl );
    },
    logOutput: function(text){
      document.getElementById('output').value +=  text + '\n';
    }
  }
```